# Widgets must be created in the main thread error in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I have a problem in Qt.

I have a external pthread that need to show a Qt Dialog.
I have created a class `WindowsManager` that contain a static function to show a Qt Dialog: `WindowsManager::ShowDialog()`

When call this function in my pthread

```
void* task(void*)
{
    WindowsManager::ShowDialog();
}
```

Then Qt shows me an Assertion Failed:

> Widgets must be created in the main thread

Can I get around this issue?

Comment: Create the widget in the main thread and share it with the thread to call `widget-> ShowDialog ()`?

Comment: @Theolodis This would not behave correctly. The methods on the object need be called in the right thread! However sending signals works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the WindowsManager ShowDialog a slot, which it will be invoked from the current thread.

Assuming the WindowsManager has been created, move the WindowsManager class to the main thread: -

```
windowsManager->moveToThread(QApplication::instance()->thread());
```

Then invoke the slot with QMetaObject::invoke